# Preferred approach for changing UITableViewCell content based on cell width

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8, autolayout

I have a dynamic custom `UITableViewCell` that takes advantage of auto layout.

I vary the text content of a label, depending on the width of the cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ...
    cell.someLabel.text = CGRectGetWidth(cell.bounds) < 321 ? @"Concise" : @"Much longer blurb";

    return cell;
}
```

`reloadData` is called during orientation transition to update the label.

While this happens to work, I imagine there's a better way to handle this that doesn't involve the overhead of reloading the tableView.

(None of the constraints need to be changed.  The label is in the same place, but simply shows different content when there's more room for it.)

- Should I subclass `UILabel` and change the text in `-didMoveToSuperview`?
- Is it possible to change the text in `-layoutSubViews`?  (Wouldn't that cause another layout pass because the text was changed?)

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: "that doesn't involve the overhead of reloading the tableView" I think the first thing to do is rethink why you believe that reloading the table view is "overhead". It is quite efficient, since only the visible table cell data is actually fetched freshly - and your data model should be completely efficient or you're doing it wrong.

Comment: It just seems like overkill, Matt.  Auto layout is already happening, as a result of auto rotation, and I'm guessing it could be handled right within the layout pass that's already occurring.  I just don't know enough about auto layout to know how the cell or label should handle it.

Comment: But the issue I don't mention is the subtle flicker of the reload that you wouldn't see without the reload.  It would look nicer if I didn't have to reload the table, and it simply auto-rotated and redrew itself (with different contents).  Possible?

Comment: Without reload, where would the "different contents" come from?

Comment: This all came about by trying to learn how to make an IB_Designable custom control.  The label was subclassed and had an IBInspectable property that told it what its contents would be, which initially came from `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  The situation is that the label already knows its contents, and just needs to alternate between *short version* of contents and *long version* of contents.

Comment: Isn't a reload of the data required after rotation? Since the number of cells able to be displayed can change after the rotation, the new cells have to be loaded.

Comment: `-reloadData` isn't required after rotation.  The tableView will automatically query its dataSource when new cells become visible as a result of rotation.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Although I would have thought that it simply calls reload data but perhaps it only reloads the newly visible cells.

Comment: Have you considered simply adding two text views and fading between the two? I.e. alpha on short label transitions from 1 to 0 then the long label transitions from alpha of 0 to 1?

Comment: That would work, but I'd have to add some constraints, along with code to animate the property changes.  But unless I'm missing something, auto layout is already doing all the heavy lifting behind the scenes, and I'm hoping to be able to hook into that.  The cells are being redrawn after the layout pass.  Is it acceptable to change the label text within the layout pass?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply adding this logic to `layoutSubviews` should do the trick. It's called each time the auto layout engine does its thing.

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    self.someLabel.text = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) < 321 ? @"Concise" : @"Much longer blurb";
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

Comment: I'm using `-viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`  I'd like to try to handle it all within auto layout (as the visible cells already are reacting to the transition without the table needing to be reloaded).  I just have to discover where to actually change the text.

Comment: If the visual cells are already reacting then why not put the change of text wherever that reaction takes place?

Comment: That's my thinking, but I don't know which method to put it in, and I've never tinkered with `-layoutSubviews` if that's even the right method to override.  Will dive into the unknown in a few days and try to discover where the change of text should happen, if no one has that answer.

Comment: `layoutSubviews` is probably the way to go unless you want to do what I suggested and create your own method. `layoutSubviews` gets called each time auto layout does its thing, so changing it there should be simple enough, just remember to call super as well otherwise it might cause all sorts of weird stuff (I know from experience ;) )

Comment: I added `layoutSubviews` to my custom `UITableviewCell`, changed the label's text (based on the cell width), then called super.  It looks great, and the whole animation is back to being very smooth now that I don't have to reload the data.  If you'll update your answer, I will mark it as accepted.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great! I changed the answer to a `layoutSubviews` solution instead.